# how to convert csv to xml with different headers

Tags: c#, xml, linq, csv

I have a csv with different column headers and I want to convert this to an XML payload.

The csv looks like following.

```
TEST1,APPLICATION_NAME,START_TIME,STOP_TIME,SERVICE_DESCRIPTION,FILING_STATUS,TIME_OF_LAST_UPDATE,RECORD_STATUS,ERROR_MESSAGE
,,20120101000000ES,20140131000000ES,New FGH Application,,,
,,20140304000000ES,20161231000000ES,New FGH Application,,,
,,20150109000000ES,20201231000000ES,New FGH Application,,,
TEST2,app,TOL,QUEUED
,nits,20120101000000ES,20201231000000ES
```

I tried to do this with Linq but couldn't figure out a way. Also I don't really want to specify columns like in the following example.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387090

please note that this csv has different column headers.

The output I am expecting is;

```
<Root>
  <TEST1>
    <APPLICATION_NAME></APPLICATION_NAME>
    <START_TIME>20120101000000ES</START_TIME>
    <STOP_TIME>20140131000000ES</STOP_TIME>
    <SERVICE_DESCRIPTION>New NITS Application</SERVICE_DESCRIPTION>
    <FILING_STATUS></FILING_STATUS>
    <TIME_OF_LAST_UPDATE></TIME_OF_LAST_UPDATE>
    <RECORD_STATUS></RECORD_STATUS>
  </TEST1>
  <TEST1>    
    <APPLICATION_NAME></APPLICATION_NAME>
    <START_TIME>20140304000000ES</START_TIME>
    <STOP_TIME>20161231000000ES</STOP_TIME>
    <SERVICE_DESCRIPTION>New NITS Application</SERVICE_DESCRIPTION>
    <FILING_STATUS></FILING_STATUS>
    <TIME_OF_LAST_UPDATE></TIME_OF_LAST_UPDATE>
    <RECORD_STATUS></RECORD_STATUS>
  </TEST1>
  <TEST1>
    <APPLICATION_NAME></APPLICATION_NAME>
    <START_TIME>20150109000000ES</START_TIME>
    <STOP_TIME>20201231000000ES</STOP_TIME>
    <SERVICE_DESCRIPTION>New NITS Application</SERVICE_DESCRIPTION>
    <FILING_STATUS></FILING_STATUS>
    <TIME_OF_LAST_UPDATE></TIME_OF_LAST_UPDATE>
    <RECORD_STATUS></RECORD_STATUS>
  </TEST1>
  <TEST2>
    <app>nits</app>
    <TOL>20120101000000ES</TOL>
    <QUEUED>20201231000000ES</QUEUED>
 </TEST2>
</root>
```

Thanks for your help.

update: this is what I started off with.

```
string[] headers = lines[0].Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim('\"')).ToArray();
var xml = new XElement("root",
    lines.Where((line, index) => index > 0).Select(line => new XElement("TEST",
        line.Split(',').Select((column, index) => new XElement(headers[index], column)))));
```

Comment: How did you try to convert it with LINQ? Please show some code.

Comment: A "CSV" with multiple multiple header lines isn't a CSV, it's two CSV concatenated. You need to parse the CSV first and put the values in objects, *then* use eg XDocument to create an XML document from the list of objects

Comment: I am sorry. updated the description with what I started off with.

Comment: First try to get the parsing right, then try to generate XML. These are two different problems. The code you posted doesn't parse the CSV, it simply splits a line

Comment: it actually does parse the CSV. look at the second line. Maybe I can start off with one and then try to do an append?

Comment: The second line tries to both parse and translate to XML. It's almost impossible to understand or see what might be wrong. You *have* to separate the two steps - parsing the input and translating to the output format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on the linked example, you can do this

```
string[] source = File.ReadAllLines("text.csv");
string IGNORE_ROW = "XXXXX";
List<string> data = new List<string>();
string test = "";
for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
{
    string[] _str = source[i].Split(',');
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_str[0])) _str[0] = test;
    else
    {
        test = _str[0];
        _str[0] = IGNORE_ROW;
    }

    source[i] = String.Join(",", _str);
}

XElement data = new XElement("Root",
    from str in source
    where str.StartsWith(IGNORE_ROW) == false
    let fields = str.Split(',')
    select new XElement(fields[0],
        new XElement("APPLICATION_NAME", fields[1]),
        new XElement("START_TIME", fields[2]),
        new XElement("STOP_TIME", fields[3]),
        new XElement("SERVICE_DESCRIPTION", fields[4]),
        new XElement("FILING_STATUS", fields[5]),
        new XElement("TIME_OF_LAST_UPDATE", fields[6]),
        new XElement("RECORD_STATUS", fields[7])
    )
);
Console.WriteLine(data);
```

It is simply a matter for renaming the relevant elements and including them in the correct order.

**// Edited**

After reviewing the comment, it appears you are repeating the header within the data so that it can used as an element name.  If you have control over the csv generation, remove this repeated row, and simply output the test value as the first element in the csv.

If you do not have control over the csv, you can alter the text so that it can be set.  This is what the edited example does.

Comment: this one would take line 5 into consideration, which is a column header and I don't want that in the xml output.

Comment: @IndikaP I have amended the code, so that you can append the required value to the data.  Or use a some kind a loop over the data where you have better control then the linq statement.  The sample should do what you require, but read over the edit text.

Comment: @Kami- Thanks for the response. I can start off with this. If you look at the description though, it says i need the column header in line 5 as well. following data is a part of that column header in line 5. The last tag in the xml output i mentioned is differ from the ones above.

Comment: @IndikaP - I did allow for this, but failed to update all the code.  The `fields[0]` is reset to various test values, and it is used in the xml.  See the revised code.

Comment: @Kami- This one works for the Test tag but not the other column headers. If you look at the final tags those are named as  <APPLICATION_NAME2> .. etc. note the "2" after the name. After going through what you gave me, I kinda came up with a way but not sure it's the best way to do this. what I am doing is joining each header right before the actual value. something like this:
START_TIME,20120101000000ES,STOP_TIME,20140131000000ES, ...etc.
please let me know if there is a better way I can go with. 
Thanks again.

Comment: just outta curiosity, is there a that I can do this without stating the column names like "APPLICATION_NAME" etc?

Comment: @IndikaPathirage I can understand the naming of the test from `test1` to `test2` etc.  But changing the properties make little sense if they represent the same values across the board - You should review what you are trying to do to ensure this is correct.  If you still want to do this then, you are correct in that if the CSV row includes the relevant headers, they can be see as key value pairs, with the preceding value being used as an element name.  The csv row is split into `fields` and you can use the various indexes to retrieve the relevant values.

Comment: @Kami- one more question. what if the second column headers are differ from the first column headers. size-wise and name-wise? 
I updated the description.

Comment: @IndikaPathirage The length of the column does not matter, but CSV files need to have a consistent number of columns, if they do not, then you will need to use another method to parse them.

Comment: I just got to know that mine has a different number of columns actually. it makes it harder for me to parse from the above method you mentioned. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextFieldParser` to read the csv file and parse it into classes.
Then use `XDocument` to build a xml document in memory and write it to a file after its completed.